# Image does not shrink in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I'm having trouble understanding why my images don't shrink when I shrink/resize my Chrome. Can someone explain and help me?
I have been trying for a while now but I can't seem to figure it out or find the answer elsewhere. The image shrinks in firefox running on my localhost, but not inside jsfiddle. Still not working in Chrome(57.0.2987.110).

```
<div class="page">
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">
        <H1>FLEXBOX PRACTICE</H1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/1280/720" alt="Bacn">
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.page {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: pink;

}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 60vw;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: salmon;
}
    .text {
        flex-grow: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 10px;

        width: 340px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: verdana;
    }
    .images {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-shrink: 1;         
        max-width: 600px;
        width: 600px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
        .images img {           
            display: flex;
            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
            max-width: inherit;
            width: inherit;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xb4obfce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're telling the image to inherit the width of its parent, which is at 600px.

Changing the .images class to width: 100%; should make it responsive.

Comment: Thanks. In the mean time I had found the solution myself, but I will still mark your answer as the solution.